# What is wrong with my random number generator JS script?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a simple random number generator script, but it doesn't work. I have opened this in an html document, and I know I made no mistakes there as I have been working with HTML for a while. I will still show that if anybody needs it though. I have no idea what is wrong with this, but the variable randomNumber doesn't print to the screen. Any thoughts?

```
var randomNumber = math.Random();
if (randomNumber <= 0.09)
{
  randomNumber = 1;
}
else if (randomNumber >= 0.1 && randomNumber <= 0.19)
{
  randomNumber = 2;
}
else if (randomNumber >= 0.2 && randomNumber <= 0.29)
{
  randomNumber = 3;
}
else if (randomNumber >= 0.3 && randomNumber <= 0.39)
{
  randomNumber = 4;
}
else if (randomNumber >= 0.4 && randomNumber <= 0.49)
{
  randomNumber = 5;
}
else if (randomNumber >= 0.5 && randomNumber <= 0.59)
{
  randomNumber = 6;
}
else if (randomNumber >= 0.6 && randomNumber <= 0.69)
{
  randomNumber = 6;
}
else if (randomNumber >= 0.7 && randomNumber <= 0.79)
{
  randomNumber = 7;
}
else if (randomNumber >= 0.8 && randomNumber <= 0.89)
{
  randomNumber = 8;
}
else if (randomNumber >= 0.9)
{
  randomNumber = 9;
}
else if (rn2 <= 0.09)
{
  randomNumber = 10;
}
// rn2's purpose is do dictate whether the variable randomNumber will be 10
var rn2 = math.Random();
document.write("The number is " + randomNumber + ".");
```

Comment: Your script to get a random number could be replaced by `Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1`

Comment: Obligatory `int getRandomNumber() { return 4; /*chosen by fair dice roll. guaranteed to be random.*/ }` Just kidding, find the answers below.

Comment: Also, what do you want to happen when the random value is 0.692, 0.491 etc?

Comment: Flagged for just being a typographical error that's unlikely to help future readers. All that was wrong was he was doing `math.Random()` instead of `Math.random()` (notice the changes in capitalization.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) instead of `math.Random()`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/35xnj/)